# Hibernate/JPA issue with VARCHAR2( 32767 CHAR) : ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to insert 5000 characters data into VARCHAR2(32767 CHAR) db column. It is working fine with Normal JDBC program. But when I tried to run with JPA program it is not working.

Clear Summary:
I've created a table having a column VARCHAR2(32767 CHAR)

My JPA Code is trying to insert large string into this field which is of 5000 CHARS.

when I ran this code with `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` then the field get created LONG instead of VARCHAR2(32676 CHAR) and I'm able to insert data.

But when I created table Manually with column VARCHAR2(32767 CHAR). And tried to insert code from JPA. Still JPA internally converting that column as LONG and trying to insert.

So I'm getting ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column.

Any solution on this?

Comment: How does the mapping look like?

Comment: @Column(name = "position", columnDefinition="VARCHAR2 32767 CHAR")
 private String position;

Comment: Shouldn't it be VARCHAR2(32767 CHAR)

Comment: @Simon, Then what it should be?

Answer (score 0):

Oops!!
Issue is with Oracle12c dialect. 
I've updated my application.properties with 12cDialect (spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect). It is working.

Note: Just cross-check your ODBC driver version. if it is old update it.
[CLOB is recommended if data is large]

Thanks